# what happened to c:\python27?

Tags: enthought, pyinstaller, canopy

I just installed EPD/CANOPY on a new Win7 PC and wanted to make sure it would work for scripts that have been developed in other environments.

I'm using a known-good script, with valid data, and trying to (re)generate an executable with pyinstaller-2.1.  It seems a couple .dlls are missing from the final package but they do exist, under C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\Scripts.

Looks like a simple path problem...that's when I noticed there is no C:\Python27 directory!

Also, the above path is not in the Windows environment variable, that looks like C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts

Background, I had installed pyinstaller with pip, per instructions https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761. From the Canopy Command Prompt, PyInstaller shows up OK with "pip list" and responds to its --version prompt so I think it is OK.

Some other way to generate executables would be useful in the interim but the general question is still how to get these paths straight for all comers?

Comment: Canopy 1.x uses a `venv`-based virtual environment which is described at http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

Comment: Hmmm, thanks.   So the missing mk2_avx.dll is in the core Canopy area, not either the system or user environments.

Comment: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html indicates I can get an "EDP-like" environment that has C:\Python27.  Should that be necessary?  I'm presuming that anything I run in the user sandbox which goes looking for \Python27 will get redirected somehow.

Comment: System environment is irrelevant. User environment inherits from the core, so a program running in User will see that DLL. I don't know how to tell pyinstaller that it needs to use the venv standards.

Comment: The "EDP-like" environment is EPD-like from the user perspective but still uses a virtual environment and will present the same issues for pyinstaller.

Comment: Double hmmm.   Thanks again.   <runs off to play with some textbook examples and see what happens...>